# Formatting a string in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

I have a long SQL statement in vscode with the python extension on MacOSX. Pressing command + k and command + f does not format, so that the lines are wrapped in order to see them on one screen:

```
sql_statement = "SQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statementSQL statement"
```

This should format, so that it fits on the screen. How am i able to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it in settings:
Editor: Word Wrap: On